# Integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$

Tags: calculus

Consider the following integration
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$
B thinks this expression should be written as
$$\int_{-1}^0\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}+\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$
which is not convergent, but A thinks it is zero because it is an odd function with the symmetric region so the integration is zero. B thinks that the integration doesn't converge, so we are not allowed to use the properties of integration.

I think B is correct. Right?

Comment: don't forget $dx$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Student B is correct in the sense that traditionally, this integral cannot be evaluated. However, the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of this integral exists (the 'intuitive' way to extend integrals into areas where they do not converge) and is indeed 0.